# how to display particular record in details view by fetching only that record which is stored in a session variable?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a details view to display information of teachers. I want that information of only that teacher is displayed who have logged in using his ID. This Id is stored in Teacher table(apart from the login table). I am using a Session variable to store the logged in Id.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please make sure you [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to improve your question. It will make it easier for others to understand it and help you out.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is solved now. I'd keep this in mind from next time.